# Time stamp not getting updated in Informatica 9.5

Tags: informatica

In informatica 9.5.1 how to update time stamp ? I'm not getting correct time stamp. This issue is facing while workflow check in and check out.

Comment: Hi Alna, can you please elaborate your question. Provide sample input data and expected result

Comment: Timestamp is not updating in workflows during check in and check out . Facing this issue in informatica 9.5.1 version. The workflows is not updating with correct time. If I did check in or check out a workflow today means it should show today's date, but it is showing 2018. If I did multiple times check in check out means the time stamp of each iteration got updated with seconds difference.

Comment: This is very strange. Informatica should update date and time stamp of check-in time. Is it happening for all workflows or specific one? Since when this is happening - recent change or forever like this? Can you try closing client, repo and re-check ?